# ESXi host won't power on, in current state (powerd off)

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, esxi

I had this working Windows Server 2012 VM, that needed a reboot. After I rebooted the vm, changed some settings (attached a dvd drive), it would boot up again.

Now it says:

```
Failed - The attempted operation cannot be performed in the current state (Powered off).
```

I can't revert the setting, because of this state,
I checked the host machine, tried booting it from there, but no luck.
Also tried to reboot, reset, etc but nothing worked, it is not in the running VMs list.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I made changes to the VM using Remote Console (removed ISO from DVD).  Received the same error.  I had to un-register the VM, then re-register the VM and now it boots fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only needed a few pieces of data so I did the following: downloaded the VDI files, placed them in a desktop VM downloaded the files and removed the VM on ESXi.
I'll check your answer as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you for detailed and proffessional response - works great!!